# Можно ли писать "обязательно" после "сегодня ЖЕ"?

Tags: стилистика, наречия

Верно ли стилистически писать наречие *обязательно* после наречия *сегодня* с усилительной частицей *же*? Например: *Сегодня же обязательно сделаю*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь нет *явных* стилистических просчётов, поскольку частица относится к "сегодня" и подчёркивает *незамедлительность* обещанного действия, а "обязательно" указывает на *твёрдость намерений* его осуществить. Тем не менее, для большей ясности я изменил бы порядок слов:

> Обязательно сделаю, (и) сегодня же.

Comment: Хорошая заметка. Какие можете посоветовать материалы по стилистике?

Comment: "Тем не менее" в последнем предложении у Вас союз или частица? Больше похоже на союз, но тогда запятая точно не нужна. Если частица, то запятая в качестве исключения (авторская пунктуация) допустима, но в данном случае такая модальность выглядела бы сомнительно.

Answer (score 4):

Подозреваемой тавтологичности или избыточности здесь нет. В НКРЯ точно такой формы встретить не удалось, но аналог ей нашёлся вполне достойный.

> "А как прилетим, ― думал он, ― сегодня же непременно купаться". [И.
>   Грекова. На испытаниях (1967)]

Comment: Действительно. А какие можете посоветовать материалы по стилистике?